# Updating data in Firebase deletes unused values

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database in Firebase:

[image]

Whenever I try to update some items, it deletes the unaltered ones, instead of letting them keep their values. I have the following code:

```
FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("FirebaseLink");

MyDatabaseRecord databaserecord = new MyDatabaseRecord
{
    Plate1 = EntryPlate1.Text.ToString(),
    Plate2 = EntryPlate2.Text.ToString()                       
 };
string restName = "Rest1";
await firebaseClient.Child("Menus/" + restName).PutAsync(databaserecord); //Adicionar reload à página 2 após o click no botão de adicionar ou noutro click


EntryPlate1.Text = "";
EntryPlate2.Text = "";
```

MyDatabaseRecord.cs:

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Plate1 { get; set; }
    public string Plate2 { get; set; }
}
```

What I mean by "it deletes the unaltered ones" is that, in this example, although my only changes are to "Plate1" and "Plate2" values, when its executed, it deletes "Plate3" from the database, instead of just replacing the ones I'm targeting.

What can I change to my code in order for this to work like intended?

Comment: this is how document based databases work.  You are not modifying individual columns like you do in SQL, you are updating a single atomic record.    If you only want to replace certain fields, you need to retrieve the existing record, modify the fields, and then update the db with the modified record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PutAsync` method is the equivalent of a HTTP PUT call of the Firebase REST API, which rewrites the data at the given path with the data that you pass into the call. If you want to instead **patch** the data, use `PatchAsync` which performs a [selective update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update) only overwriting the properties that you pass in.